# Fill elements with data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want do build some pictures albuns that the user can click on it and go to a image gallery with pictures of that album.
Each algum have a thumbnail picture, a title and a link for the pictures. 
In my code, I can get all the data from database. But it doesn't appear on the website.
I know I'm doing something wrong. But don't know what...
So, here's my code:

In my model, I have this code:

```
public List<Entities.Portfolio> GetAlbuns()
    {
        List<Entities.Portfolio> port = new List<Entities.Portfolio>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("usp_get_all_albuns", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                port.Add(new Entities.Portfolio()
                {
                    Imagem = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0),
                    Link = reader.GetString(1),
                    Title = reader.GetString(2)
                });
            }

        }
        return port;
    }
```

In my controller, I'll call the method:

```
PortfolioController pcontroller = new PortfolioController();
protected List<Entities.Portfolio> GetAlbuns()
    {
        return pcontroller.GetAlbuns();
    }
```

And in my ASP.NET page, I have this:

```
 <div class="freshdesignweb" id="Albuns" runat="server">
    <% foreach(var items in GetAlbuns())
       { %>
           <!-- start article 1 -->
                <article class="border c-two" style="background-image:url('<% items.Imagem.ToArray(); %>"')">
                    <div style="opacity: 0;" class="fdw-background">
                        <h4><a href="<% Eval(items.Link.ToString()); %>" style="color:#fff;"><% Eval(items.Title.ToString()); %></a></h4>

                        <p class="fdw-port">
                            <a href="<% Eval(items.Link.ToString()); %>">Abrir Álbum <span class="vg-icon">→</span></a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <!-- end article 1 -->
    <%} %>
```

I can get all the data well, I tested in debug mode. But it doesn't appear in the page.
I know I'm doing something wrong, can you help me to understand how to fix this?

In my investigation I read about

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the # sign in front of Eval:

```
"<%# Eval(items.Link.ToString()) %>"
```

Comment: hello. Thanks for your reply. I added the # signal, but now it says that the name 'items' does not exist in the current context.